# partial class naming for asp.net web form default template

Tags: asp.net

My company has visual studio asp.net web site projects.  When adding a new web form using the default webform template it will automatically create the codefile with the partial class name using the path and the filename you selected.  For example, if you added a new web form named Default.aspx to the path User/Feature/ the partial class name will be User_Feature_Default.  This works fine.  The issue (which may not be an issue) is that of course if you move those files around it will not update the partial class name.  Makes sense.  Visual Studio is only going to do so much tweaking.  My question is whether or not our development group should update these partial class names when the files are moved into new folders mainly for consistancy sake?  Will this cause any other problems?  I can't think of any.

Comment: Just an FYI: you may find that Web Application Projects make better sense. Web Site "projects" are the only "projects" in all of Visual Studio that act this way.

Comment: That's actually how this was discovered when doing some proof of concept for converting web site projects to web application projects there were some issues with conflicts due to copy and past of aspx files and multiple aspx files using same inherits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a possibility of adding new .aspx pages with the same name in those locations, I would advocate renaming. I've run into issues in the past where I had Copy+Pasted a file to have a template to start from. The file name changes, but the class name and .aspx Inherits attribute remain the same.

Because the code-behind pages are partial classes, it will happily let you add multiple classes. But I think those then end up being compiled into a single page class which can spell problems if you have Load/Init logic that should only fire on one of the pages, or if you have functions named the same thing.

Comment: That's what happened trying to convert web site project to web site application.